# Dúvida sobre carregamento de imagens no CSS

Tags: css

Gostaria de otimizar o carregamento de imagens do meu site de acordo com o tamanho do dispositivo que o acessa.

Minha ideia é usar media querys no css e dependendo da resolução do dispositivo carregar uma imagem de pior qualidade como background-image de uma div.

Aí me surgiu a dúvida: tudas as imagens referenciadas em um arquivo css, por exemplo: .classe1 { background-image: url('imagem.png') }, são carregadas automaticamente, ou só são carregadas caso exista algum elemento com a .classe1 no meu html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Depende do navegador.**

Alguns navegadores podem localizar todas as imagens, inclusive aquelas que não foram usadas na página.

*Isso tem um lado positivo, afinal o usuário de desktop pode redimensionar a janela, por exemplo, então as imagens já estão salvas em cache.*

## Teste:

```
@media all and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .teste {
        background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-200-200-1.jpg');
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .teste {
        background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-200-200-2.jpg');
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
    }
}
```

## Resultado:

**Usado o Chrome 52 em Windows 10:**
[image: Chrome 52]

*Apenas obteve o definido pelo `@media all and (min-width: 1024px) {`.*

**Usado o Microsoft Edge em Windows 10:**
[image: Microsft Edge]

*Obteve todas as imagens de ambas as `@media`.*

**Usado o Firefox em Windows 10:**
[image: Firefox]

*Apenas obteve o definido pelo `@media all and (min-width: 1024px) {`.*

**Usado o Chrome (Mobile) 52 em Android 6.0.1**
[image: Chrome Mobile 52]

*Apenas obteve o definido pelo `@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {`.*

> Toda as situações o *site* foi acessado em janela maximizada atendendo os `@media` definido, exceto no Mobile, que é justamente onde deve ser exibido a outra imagem!

## Conclusão:

Cada navegador funciona de uma forma diferente, embora em geral tendem a respeitar o que está definido por `@media`, ao menos nos navegadores mais recentes!

Estes testes foram feitos por mim, por essa razão não testei em mais navegadores ou em mais situações. Entretanto algumas pessoas já fizeram testes mais completos e mais situações, você pode achar mais testes (principalmente de navegadores antigos), em https://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/.